# Coalesce in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to get the `cashassignment_id` column if the column doesn't have data then print `0` as result. But the `Cash 1` is Missing.

Cash_DataTable data:

```
cash_id    cash_name
1          cash 1
2          cash 2
3          cash 3
```

CashAssignments_DataTable data:

```
cashassignment_id    cash_id   cashassignment_valid
100                  1         0 (false)
200                  1         0 (false)
300                  1         0 (false)
```

My current linq result:

```
cash_id     cashassignment_id   cash_name
2           0                   cash 2
3           0                   cash 3
```

Note: `Cash 1` is missing, I need to show all the cash when cashassignment_valid = true else return 0 as `cashassignment_id`

```
DataTable CashStatusProc1 = new DataTable();
CashStatusProc1.Columns.Add("cash_id", typeof(Int32));
CashStatusProc1.Columns.Add("cashassignment_id", typeof(Int32));
CashStatusProc1.Columns.Add("cash_name", typeof(String));

(from Cash in Cash_DataTable.AsEnumerable()
 join CashAssignments in CashAssignments_DataTable.AsEnumerable()
      on Cash.Field<Int32>("cash_id") equals CashAssignments.Field<Int32>("cash_id")
      into JoinedCashAssignments
 from CashAssignments in JoinedCashAssignments.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where ((((CashAssignments != null ? CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid") : false) == true) || (CashAssignments == null)) )
     select new
               {
                  cash_id = Cash.Field<Int32>("cash_id"),
                  cashassignment_id = (CashAssignments != null ? CashAssignments.Field<Int32>("cashassignment_id") : 0),
                   cash_name = Cash.Field<String>("cash_name")
               }).Aggregate(CashStatusProc1, (dt, result) =>
                             {
                                 dt.Rows.Add(result.cash_id, result.cashassignment_id, result.cash_name); return dt;
                             });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not really be an answer but it might lead you in the right direction and take care of a bug or two, lets go through your code alittle.

In the where statement there are several conundrums.

```
((((CashAssignments != null ? CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid") : false) == true) || (CashAssignments == null)) )
```

First lets clean it. (flipped the != to ==)

```
(CashAssignments == null ? false : 
CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid")) == true
|| CashAssignments == null
```

Now lets look at it, you're asking if the `CashAssignments` is equal to null and if it is then you return false and the you check is `CashAssignments` equal to false then return true. this kindof means the same as

```
if (x == null || x != null) //Will always happen
```

also the `(CashAssignments == null ? false : CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid")) == true` is somewhat redundant and equals to

```
bool z;
if(CashAssignments == null) z = false;
else z = CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid")
if(z == true) // This is redundant just do the work in the else
```

so drop the `|| CashAssignments == null` from it and handle it on the first expression

```
(CashAssignments == null ? true : 
CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid"))
```

actually we can go further. what you have can be seen as

```
x == null ? true : x.value //x.value might be true or false
// Equal to
if(x == null || x.value)
```

so we can write it like this (even tinyer and more readable)

```
CashAssignments == null || 
CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid")
```

so what you are in essence asking for is if `CashAssignments` is null or if `CashAssignments.Field<Boolean>("cashassignment_valid")` is true do work

Next is the select expression

```
cash_id = Cash.Field<Int32>("cash_id"),
cashassignment_id = (CashAssignments != null ? CashAssignments.Field<Int32>("cashassignment_id") : 0),
cash_name = Cash.Field<String>("cash_name")
```

only one thing of interest here the `cashassignment_id` and its mostly cleanup for readability ( the flip on != to == is mostly my own taste)

```
cashassignment_id = CashAssignments == null ? 0 : 
                        CashAssignments.Field<Int32>("cashassignment_id")
```

Rest more or less looks good. By disectiong your code im assuming the error lays in the where statement and might have been resorted by the cleanup and redundancy removal as they overlapped in several areas.

Other things to note:

In the statement you declare as i see it `CashAssignments` twice, once as the result of the join and once more as the result of default if empty.

Also since you floor it to default, instead of `null` that you could test against `default(DataTable)` as a safety measure in-case the default is not `null` (for alot of cases it is null, one example is the default of `int` that is 0 and not null and `0 == null equals to false`